# Unexpected token with Webpack and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm new to TypeScript and relatively new to React and just trying to follow the [React & Webpack tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html). With some searching I've managed to resolve most of the issues with it being slightly out of date, except one. When I try and run Webpack to transpile the Typescript, I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module parse failed: /home/X/Projects/react-typescript-tutorial/src/index.tsx Unexpected token (7:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
|     <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
|     document.getElementById("example")
| );
```

I tried the solution mentioned in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502276/unexpected-token-webpack-configuration-issue-with-typescript-react) but it had no effect in my case. I'm not sure if this is an issue with awesome-typescript-loader at this point or with Webpack.

My webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" }
        ],

        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

And (as requested in comments) my index.tsx file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Hello } from "./components/Hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("example")
);
```

Would appreciate any help available!

Comment: Would also like to see index.tsx file

Comment: Hi @ArshabhAgarwal, I've added the index.tsx contents as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You defined both `module.rules` and `module.loaders`. When webpack sees `module.rules` it ignores `module.loaders` completely, which only exist for compatibility reasons. So your `awesome-typescript-loader` is not being used at all. To fix it simply put all rules under `modules.rules`:

```
module: {
   rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
      { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", loader: "source-map-loader" }
   ]
},
```